# css selector from child div to next adjacent div?

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have markup like this:

```
<div>
    <div class="one"></div>
</div>
<div class="two">
```

Is there any way in css that I can select class .two from class .one?

As in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/FnAFE/4/).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? I guess you want .two to turn red when you hover on .one right?

Comment: yes that's what I want... of coarse this is just a demo for what i really want

Comment: @Georgestocker actually that "duplicate" question is not what I'm asking at all. I know how to do what was asked there, in my question I was wondering if it was somehow possible to target a sibling-element (.two) of the parent element of .one..... and the answer I got was no, it's not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying is not possible using only CSS, what you can do is you can re arrange the element like this

```
<div>
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two">
</div>
```

And use

```
.one:hover + .two {
   /* Styles */
}
```

Else you can do is this (If you don't want to change the markup) [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FnAFE/2/)

```
div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: pink;
}

.two {
    height: 20px;
    background: #000;
    width: 20px;
}

div:nth-of-type(1):hover + .two {
    background: #f00;
}

.one + .two {
    background: #f00;
}
```

Comment: Note: div:nth-of-type(1) does not work in all browser(Hint: IE :P)

Comment: +1 Thanks. I had a feeling that this wasn't possible. Unfortunately your solution won't help in my case because the root div isn't empty. (That's why I wrote the markup like that in the first place.) I updated the fiddle in the question to emphasize this more clearly.

Comment: @Danield: then it can't be done; to target a sibling-element of the parent element would (obviously) require a parent-selector (which CSS still doesn't have, and won't (unfortunately) be usable with CSS 4's fast selectors). It looks like JavaScript is your only real option, unfortunately.

Comment: @Danield I got an idea that it won't be possible for you that's why I provided 2 closest ways which are possible using only CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do using jquery

script type="text/javascript">

```
    $(function () {



        $(".one").mouseover(function () {
            $(".two").css("background","red")

        });



        $(".one").mouseout(function () {

            $(".two").css("background", "");
        });
    });

</script>
```